# MUI Skeleton Generator function

Tags: reactjs, loops, next.js, material-ui

I am working on next.js project, where we are calling API and showing data on Dashboard,

While Loading data we are showing Skeleton for cards or any other UI Components for same/look-a-like view.

```
const skeletonDom = () => {
return (
  <>
    <Grid container spacing={4} xs={12}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Skeleton variant='rounded' height={320} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
        <Skeleton variant='rounded' height={200} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
        <Skeleton variant='rounded' height={200} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
        <Skeleton variant='rounded' height={200} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </>
)
```

}

if loading is true, I am showing this layout.

What I want to achieve is I want to make function which takes object as props, return me above code.

like if I input:

```
const skeletonObj = [
{
  type: 'parent',
  tag: 'Grid',
  props: {
    container: true,
    spacing: 4,
    xs: 12
  },
  children: [
    {
      type: 'child',
      tag: 'Grid',
      props: {
        item: true,
        xs: 12
      },
      children: [
        {
          type: 'child',
          tag: 'Skeleton',
          props: {
            variant: 'rounded',
            height: 320
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

]

I have tried map as well as loop but I am not able to get desire output.

Can someone write/help me to write function

like : `generateSkeleton(skeletonObj)`, that return me

```
<Grid container spacing={4} xs={12}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Skeleton variant='rounded' height={320} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
        <Skeleton variant='rounded' height={200} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
        <Skeleton variant='rounded' height={200} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
        <Skeleton variant='rounded' height={200} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will generate the UI as you expected.
One suggestion I'd give that instead of assign string value to `tag` property, assign it to the component you wants to render like `Grid`. Otherwise, you have to use `if/else` or `switch` for rendering the right component.

```
// import your Grid and Skeleton components
import {Grid , Skeleton} from "@mui/material";

const skeletonObj = [
  {
    type: "parent",
    tag: Grid,
    props: {
      container: true,
      spacing: 4,
      xs: 12
    },
    children: [
      {
        type: "child",
        tag: Grid,
        props: {
          item: true,
          xs: 12
        },
        children: [
          {
            type: "child",
            tag: Skeleton,
            props: {
              variant: "rounded",
              height: 320
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: "child",
        tag: Grid,
        props: {
          item: true,
          xs: 12
        },
        children: [
          {
            type: "child",
            tag: Skeleton,
            props: {
              variant: "rounded",
              height: 320
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

function generateSkeleton(skeleton) {
  if (!skeleton || skeleton.length <= 0) return "";

  return skeleton.map((c, idx) => {
    return <c.tag key={idx} {...c.props}>{generateSkeleton(c.children)}</c.tag>;
  });
}
```